# asp.net authorization - deny all before login except the register page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I'm using ASP.NET Authorization to deny users access to my site before logging in, but this is also blocking the Register.cshtml page.
How do I sort out my authorizations to allow this page through?

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <location path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Register.cshtml">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow Anonymous to call certain action in asp.net mvc 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568936/allow-anonymous-to-call-certain-action-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO, you should not use web.config to control the authentication of your application instead use `Authorize` attribute.

Add this in your `Global.asax` file under `RegisterGlobalFilters` method

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

or you can decorate also your controller with `[Authorize]`

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

For action which require Anonymous access use `AllowAnonymous` attribute

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult Register() {
      // This action can be accessed by unauthorized users
      return View("Register");   
   }
```

As per [Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx),

> You cannot use *routing* or web.config files to secure your MVC application. The only supported way to secure your MVC application is to apply the Authorize attribute to each controller and use the new  AllowAnonymous attribute on the login and register actions. Making security decisions based on the current area is a Very Bad Thing and will open your application to vulnerabilities.

Comment: Using these attributes, am I able to specify which roles are allowed to access certain pages?

Comment: @Neeta, yes you can there are ample material available to guide you like http://geekswithblogs.net/tyarmer/archive/2010/02/25/strongly-typed-roles-in-mvc-with-authorize-attribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are denying everyone from application by using

```
<authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Above code will override all permission given to the folder

Good idea would be Deny user folderwise and keep Register/Login/Help/Contact pages at root level.

Comment: Good advice except I don't think it's a good idea to mess up the folder structure just for authorization.

Comment: Agreed on this it will be a pain