# Web.config file does not seem to affect server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to limit folder access to allow only users with the admin role access using the following Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This file is located under the sub-directory "Views/Admin/". I have another file located under "Views/Admin/Main/" that only the admin should have access to (based on the above rules), however all test cases allow any anonymous user to access the file. I am currently only working with localhost, in case that makes a difference.

The problem is that any users are being granted access to these files. Are there any extra steps that must be taken in order for the Web.config file to be recognized?

I currently access the page through an "Admin" button, and this wrongly allows any user to access the admin page (Note that I also have code here that hides this admin button when the user is not an admin that seems to work):

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", "Admin")</li>
```

Using the following Web.config file still allows users access to the web page which makes me think there is simply an extra step that I missed along the way (Note that not even the admin should be able to access the page with these rules):

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [asp.net authorization - deny all before login except the register page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567902/asp-net-authorization-deny-all-before-login-except-the-register-page/17568891#17568891) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you using the **[Authorize]** attributes in your controllers, using the built-in ASP.Net identity mechanisms?

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Or did I completely misunderstand the question?

Comment: Well I have no idea. I've just been following tutorials here and there, and all it described was creating the Web.config file as if it would work on its own. I will look at the article and see if it helps.

Comment: Try following the tips from the article I linked to you, it contains the proper way to authorize ASP.Net access for 99% of all needs :)

Comment: Is using Web.config obsolete then? I would still like to know why the Web.config route wasn't working. But yeah, using Authorize did the trick on the first try, thank you.